# how to move column values to be titles in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have been working on a project. my issue is I have repeated column values that I would like to have titles. but nothing seems to be working

[image: my work]

so for perspective,running the code below i want to do away with the outage column. and instead have headers of 'Forced '[tot_diff,count,seconds]. same for Planned and Urgent.. bearing in mind that there are multiple entries in Asset Name column.. Thanks

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"Asset Name": 
                   list('abcdefghijklmnopqrabcdefghijklmnopqr'),
                   "Outage Type": 
                   ["Forced","Planned","Urgent"]*12,
                   "tot_diff": np.random.randint(0, 3, 36),
                   "count": np.random.randint(0, 20, 36),
                   "seconds": np.random.randint(0, 1000, 36)})

df2 = df.pivot(index="Asset Name", columns="Outage Type")
```

Comment: please u d link 'my work'

Comment: Providing a sample of your `DataFrame` as text instead of image would be great. thanks

Comment: politely , have a relook at my question. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"Asset Name": list('abcdefghijklmnopqr'),
                   "Outage Type": ["Forced","Planned","Urgent"]*6,
                   "tot_diff": np.random.randint(0, 3, 18),
                   "count": np.random.randint(0, 20, 18),
                   "seconds": np.random.randint(0, 1000, 18)})

df2 = df.pivot(index="Asset Name", columns="Outage Type")
```

`df` is the input, similar to your dataframe, and `df2` is the output, with separate columns for the different `Outage Type`.

### **EDIT**

Given that you have changed your question since I answered, so that there are now duplicate `Asset Name` values, the above no longer works for you.

Taking the same format as the image in your question:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Asset Name": 
                   list('aaabbbcccdddeeefffaaabbbcccdddeeefff'),
                   "Outage Type": 
                   ["Forced","Planned","Urgent"]*12,
                   "tot_diff": np.random.randint(0, 3, 36),
                   "count": np.random.randint(0, 20, 36),
                   "seconds": np.random.randint(0, 1000, 36)})
```

If there are multiple asset name values, you will need to do one of the following:

Only convert your "Outage Type" values to columns:

```
df2 = df.pivot(columns="Outage Type")

df2.head()
#Out[23]: 
#            Asset Name                tot_diff  ...  count seconds               
#Outage Type     Forced Planned Urgent   Forced  ... Urgent  Forced Planned Urgent
#0                    a     NaN    NaN      1.0  ...    NaN   823.0     NaN    NaN
#1                  NaN       a    NaN      NaN  ...    NaN     NaN   858.0    NaN
#2                  NaN     NaN      a      NaN  ...   19.0     NaN     NaN  719.0
#3                    b     NaN    NaN      1.0  ...    NaN   605.0     NaN    NaN
#4                  NaN       b    NaN      NaN  ...    NaN     NaN   950.0    NaN

#[5 rows x 12 columns]
```

- This looks messy, because there are so many `nan` values from all the additional columns.

Or choose a method of aggregation to the duplicate rows (where `Asset Name` and `Outage Type` are the same:

```
df2 = df.pivot_table(index="Asset Name", columns="Outage Type", aggfunc='mean')

df2.head()
#Out[25]: 
#             count                seconds  ...        tot_diff               
#Outage Type Forced Planned Urgent  Forced  ... Urgent   Forced Planned Urgent
#Asset Name                                 ...                               
#a             13.0    11.0   18.0   693.5  ...  472.0      1.5     0.5    1.0
#b             10.0     9.5    4.5   410.5  ...  147.5      1.5     0.5    1.0
#c              5.0     3.5   13.5   152.5  ...  546.0      1.5     1.0    1.5
#d             16.5     9.5   10.5   427.5  ...  106.0      0.0     2.0    0.5
#e             10.5     6.5   13.5   371.0  ...  405.5      1.0     0.5    0.5

#[5 rows x 9 columns]
```

- I have chosen to take the `mean` of the duplicate rows here, but there are more options available.

Comment: What is the data that will be in these three columns?  To be able to do this, you have to fill the columns with something.  It would be helpful if you could add and expected output to your question to know what the end result should look like.

Comment: no, so instead of having multiple 'forced',' planned' and 'urgent' so that the tot_diff,'count','seconds' column values will now be under the header 'forced outage time', .'forced outtage count' for planned and urgent as well.. the "outage column will be gone completely. hope u get what i am trying to do...thanks

Comment: That is what I have suggested,  However, there are more columns because you also have planned and urgent in the outage column (therefore 9 instead of 3).

Comment: my bad.. thanks a lot..really appreciate the assist.. been stuck all day.. do have a lovely day

Comment: No problem!  I glad it works for you.

Comment: one question though.. your example did not take into consideration asset name column has multiple entries..."Asset Name": list('abcdefghijklmnopqrabcdefghijklmnopqr') . thanks

Comment: You have amended your question and put my answer in it!  That wasn't a part of the question when I gave this answer.

Comment: thanks for your effort, what i did was "reset_df.loc[reset_df['Outage type']=='Forced Outage']" for the 3 outage then i merge on 'outer' worked fine for me.